# @Url.Action does not reach my controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a class for my Ajax call, like this:

```
function sendAjaxCustom(DataType, Type, Url, Ctype, Data) {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: DataType,
        type: Type,
        url: Url,
        contentType: Ctype,
        data: Data,
        success: function (result) {
            return result;

        }
    })
}
```

In my view I am passing parameters like:

```
var result = sendAjaxCustom("json", "POST", '@Url.Action("ErrorStat","Ranking")', "application/json; charset=utf-8", JSON.stringify({ "regionalManager": tmpString }));
```

The problem is when pass `@Url.Action("ErrorStat","Ranking")`, it does not work, that means will not reach my controller to get data.

Comment: What do you mean _it does not work_? What is happening. What is the result of `'@Url.Action("ErrorStat","Ranking")'`? (the value of `Url`)

Comment: Why did you define parameters for sendAjaxCustom function?

Comment: seems in the javascript class which I created in a js file,@Url is not recognized,

Comment: @SezerTürkdal because I don't wana create Ajax everytime

Comment: @StephenMuecke could be that I can not use razor in a separate js file?

Comment: If your `var result = sendAjaxCustom(...)` code is in an separate js file, then it would not work (razor code is not parsed in external files)

Comment: @StephenMuecke what should I do then?

Comment: That depends on how your calling it. Typically you use a `data-url="@Url.Action(...)"` attribute in the element your handling, and then get it in the handler e.g. `$(someElement).click(function() { var url = $(this).data('url'); ... `